# date() : First monday of first week of month?

Tags: php

I am actually trying to make a monthly reward system with a "stamp" interface.
For that, I want to use an HTML Table with 1 cell = 1 day, starting Monday.

Here is my problem (and the solution is probably easy to find !) : Monday isn't the first day of month - not for all month, atleast. How can I ask strtotime() & date() to show the date Y-m-d for :

- "monday of first week of month" ?
- "sunday of last week of month" ?

I'm expecting result like this for 2019-08 :

- 2019-07-29
- 2019-09-01

I did not find it on PHP Documentation but is there a way to place a third argument on date() to set up the date ?

Like that, I could have done something like this :

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday'), '2019-08-01');
```

**EDIT :**

Based on @Vidal answer here is what I tried, but I got a strange PHP reaction :

```
$first_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first monday 2019-08 - 7 days"));
$last_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last sunday 2019-09"));
$last_date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last sunday 2019-09 + 7 days"));
echo $first_date; ?><br>
echo $last_date; ?><br>
echo $last_date2; ?><br>
```

Output :

```
2019-07-29
2019-08-25
2019-09-08
```

I don't know why. Did you also notice that I need to set $last_date & $last_date2 to 2019-09 instead of 2019-08 ?

Comment: Makes no sense, 7-29 is not in Aug and 9-01 is not in Aug.  So how can it be OF MONTH 08?  7-29 is the last Monday in July, which also happens to be the last week situated in July.

Comment: please see my updated answer ```last sunday of 2019-08```

Comment: Also if you want to get the next monday and sunday of the month you will have to increment 1 month not 7 days.

Comment: If you struggle with such a problem, why not write some kind of algorithm on your own? It should not be too hard to do this, and it looks like a really good exercise to learn some TDD

Comment: @p. Jerome did my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to work with the DateTime object.

```
/* 
I'm expecting result like this for 2019-08 :
"monday of first week of month" => 2019-07-29
"sunday of last week of month" => 2019-09-01
*/
$month = "2019-08";
$date = date_create($month."-02")
  ->modify("last Monday")
  ->format('l, d-m-Y')
;
echo $date."<br>";

$date = date_create("last Day of ".$month)
  ->modify("-1 Day")
  ->modify("next Sunday")
  ->format('l, d-m-Y')
;
echo $date."<br>";

/* Output
Monday, 29-07-2019
Sunday, 01-09-2019
*/
```

Comment: Better get feedback from the OP, but I think this will fail in October, for instance. But it is a good approach, just use "first day of" and "Monday/Sunday this week". No need to change dates.

Answer (score 3):

Do a loop for year, month.

```
echo date("j, d-M-Y", strtotime("first monday of 2019-08"));
echo date("j, d-M-Y", strtotime("last sunday of 2019-08"));
```

Hope it helps.

[PHP Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by changing some things to your code:

1) If the first monday is > 2 and <= 7, you have to remove 7 days to actually get the first monday

2) I added the '+ 7 days' on another line of code. It didn't work if I had 'last sunday of XXXX-XX + 7 days'

3) To get the last sunday based on your desired outputs, I compared the last sunday of the month with the total number of days in the month - 7. If it's bigger than that (25 for example), it means that it's not the last sunday

```
$year = 2019;
$month = 8;

if($month < 10)
    $month = "0" . $month;
$currentDate = $year . "-" . $month;

if(date("d", strtotime("first monday of " . $currentDate)) > 2 && date("d", strtotime("first monday of " . $currentDate)) <= 7) 
    $first_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first monday of " . $currentDate . " -7 days"));
else
    $first_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first monday of " . $currentDate));
if(date("d",strtotime("last sunday of " . $currentDate)) > date('t') - 7)
{
    $last_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last sunday of " . $currentDate));
    $last_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($last_date . " +7 days")); //working when you add days like that. doesn't work if I put + 7 days in the 'last sunday of'...
}
else
    $last_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last sunday of " . $currentDate));
echo $first_date . "<br>";
echo $last_date . "<br>";
```