# PHP - Get Week's start date and end date by month-year

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Thank you in advance

I searched for so many solutions but I did not get what I need

For an example - I want to get all the weeks and it's a start date and end date

Like if I say `September-2020` then I need all the weeks with start and end date

The output should like below (**Monday should be the first day of a week** so the week is from `Monday-Sunday`)

```
Week 1 ->  2020-08-31 To  2020-09-06
Week 2 ->  2020-09-07 To  2020-09-13
Week 3 ->  2020-09-14 To  2020-09-20
Week 4 ->  2020-09-21 To  2020-09-27
Week 5 ->  2020-09-28 To  2020-10-04
```

Comment: What have you tried? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please share that what is missing in my question if anything you feel like?

Comment: @RonakSolanki please share effort that you put into solution finding, did you write any lines of code that we can try improve? How do you want to detect first Monday of any month?

Comment: `(new \DateTimeImmutable())->modify("first day of this month")` will modify the datetime to current months first day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The first day of the current month in php using date\_modify as DateTime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094797/the-first-day-of-the-current-month-in-php-using-date-modify-as-datetime-object)

Comment: Hello all, i don't want the first day of month
i want all the weeks for a month and it's week's start and end date as shown at last in this question

Comment: I think the question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57463978/date-first-monday-of-first-week-of-month